# Is it more efficient to draw a circle with ccCircle?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm hoping to create about 50-80 'balls' on the screen and each ball is an object of a class extending CCNode. Each ball will be about `20 x 20px`.

Would it be more efficient to

- override `void draw()` and use `ccDrawCircle()`
- or make a picture and make a CCSprite with it (it'll needed be added to the node)?

Comment: If it's anything like cocos2d-iphone (individual ccDraw* calls are not batched) then multiple sprites with CCSpriteBatchNode will be faster. But until you have a performance issue it doesn't actually matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most effective way to draw multiple nodes, that use single material (texture) is `CCSpriteBatchNode`.

```
// we create base bach node with texture
CCSpriteBatchNode *batch = CCSpriteBatchNode::create(textureFile, 50 /* initial capacity of node */);

// then we create our sprites with the same texture
CCSprite::sprite = CCSprite::create(textureFile);
batch->addChild(sprite);
```

`CCSpriteBatchNode` can contain only `CCSprite`s with the same texture, that used for batch node, but all sprites are drawed in single function call (batch drawing).

Color and opacity of every sprite can be changed. To colorize sprites you can create white-colored texture of ball. When you use `setColor` method, white color will be transformed to color, that specified in `setColor`

Comment: How would `CCTextureCache` compare to batching?

Comment: `CCSprite` and `CCSpriteBatchNode` use `CCTextureCache` to get texture, when you call create. So, texture will be loaded to memory only once